# Java compiling .java with 'extends' fails

Tags: java

I am trying to compile the pentaho samples on OSX from [here](https://github.com/pentaho/pentaho-reporting/tree/master/engine/samples).

[Sample1.java](https://github.com/pentaho/pentaho-reporting/blob/master/engine/samples/source/org/pentaho/reporting/engine/classic/samples/Sample1.java) extends AbstractReportGenerator.java.

I have exported the CLASSPATH in the console to include the pwd:

```
export CLASSPATH=/Users/xxx/java-dev/pentaho/:/Users/xxx/java-dev/pentaho/lib/
```

I have compiled `AbstractReportGenerator.java` successfully using `javac`, into the same folder as the `Sample1.java` file, however when I try and compile `Sample1.java` it always fails with 3 errors related to `AbstractReportGenerator`.

Any suggestion on the cause and solution ?

Folder structure:

```
Working Folder >
 - Sample1.java
 - AbstractReportGenerator.java
 - AbstractReportGenerator.class
 - AbstractReportGenerator$1.class
 - AbstractReportGenerator$OutputType.class
 - lib
   - pentaho .jar files
```

Command:

```
javac -cp "lib/*" Sample1.java
Sample1.java:41: error: cannot find symbol
public class Sample1 extends AbstractReportGenerator
                             ^
  symbol: class AbstractReportGenerator
Sample1.java:61: error: cannot find symbol
      final ClassLoader classloader = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
                                          ^
  symbol: method getClass()
Sample1.java:132: error: package AbstractReportGenerator does not exist
    new Sample1().generateReport(AbstractReportGenerator.OutputType.PDF, outputFilename);
                                                        ^
Note: Sample1.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
3 errors
```

Comment: Is `AbstractReportGenerator` in your classpath (after compilation)?

Comment: On Windows or Linux?

Comment: O/S is MAC, the class path is the present working folder and the compiled classes (AbstractReportGenerator.class, AbstractReportGenerator$1.class, AbstractReportGenerator$OutputType.class) are in the same folder as Sample1.java

Comment: You compile the class to the local folder, though you instruct the compiler to look in the `lib` directory for classes. You should modify your javac instrcution to something like `javac -cp ./lib:./target -d ./target AbstratReportGenerator.java Sample1.java`

Comment: Try using .:lib/* instead of just lib/*. You are telling the compiler to look in lib but *not* in the current directory.

Comment: @immbis - thanks just tried thst (javac -cp ".:lib/*" Sample1.java) the errors are identical.

Comment: @Roman Vottner - thatns for helping, bu that command results in "javac: file not found: AbstratReportGenerator.java:

Comment: Did you change the package name of the classes ? You have to compile at the root package if you are compiling cross-packages

Comment: @crankshaft My bad, I put in a typo in `AbstractReportGenerator.java`

Comment: 1. In bash, `*` doesn't expand to a directory's contents if wrapped in quotes. 2. In the cases where `*` _does_ expand, it will be a space-separated list, where you need a colon-separated list if files for `javac`'s `-cp` argument.

Comment: Did you change the package name of the `AbstractReportGenerator.java` file in some way? This should have the same package name as the `Sample1.java` file. I wonder why the former file was able to build while the later one fails.

Comment: Don't edit your question with the answer. Instead, add an answer yourself. Quite often people just quickly parse through the question and only carefully look at answers, especially accepted answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks so much for all the suggestions, after adding a target folder, this suggestion from @Roman Vottner finally worked:

```
javac -cp ./lib/*:./target -d ./target AbstractReportGenerator.java Sample1.java
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```bash
javac -cp lib/*:. Sample1.java
```

Comment: He's trying to compile the file and not to execute it yet ;)

Comment: Thanks it was typo :)

Comment: @victor vosa - thanks, but that results in 3 same 3 errors.

Comment: This will not work if lib contains more than one file/directory, as `*` will expand to a space-separated list, and `-cp` needs a colon-separated one.

Comment: Escape the asterisk so the shell doesn't expand it. Then the wildcard classpath will be expanded in accordance with https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html#CBHHCGFB or https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/classpath.html#CBHHCGFB.

Comment: @LewBloch should work like this, with no escaping of any kind on Linux and Windows, and most likely on Mac too. I think the real problem is the package name of the classes, and the directory from which the command is ran.